# jquery on certain option select on first select list, enable second select list

Tags: jquery, html-select, prop

I'm trying to solve a situation where you have two select lists and on first and second option from first list, second list gets enabled.

Ok, I have `#decide` and `#day` select lists, `#day` is disabled by default. If User would select option `yes:` or `maybe:` from `#decide` list, `#day` list would get enabled with

```
$('#day').prop('disabled', false);
```

else or if the any other option is selected it would give back that disabled property to #day:

```
$('#day').prop('disabled', true);
```

currently I have only html:

```
 <select id="decide" name="decide" class="span4">
    <option value="0" selected="selected">--</option>
    <option value="yes">yes:</option>
    <option value="maybe">maybe:</option>
    <option value="no">no</option>
    <option value="nevermind">nevermind</option> 
</select>
<select id="day" name="day" class="span4" disabled>
    <option value="0" selected="selected">--</option>
    <option value="1">monday</option>
    <option value="2">tuesday</option>
    <option value="3">saturday</option>
    <option value="4">sunday</option> 
</select>
```

and idea to solve it with parts of jquery code qouted

here is jsfiddle with current situation: http://jsfiddle.net/3hwzK/

Comment: Have you tried anything? There's no JS in your fiddle. This is not a "solve my problem" forum. You need to give it a go yourself fist. We'll help you fix issues, not write it for you.

Comment: yea I tried of course... because of that I have written what js I have used, but I've deleted from fiddle because it was not working... Main problem I had is that my values from first list are not all ordered numbers as on second list... that's where I get stucked... if you do not believe me, that's your thing then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this,

```
          $("#decide").change(function (){
              if(this.value == "yes" || this.value == "maybe"){
                   $("#day").removeAttr("disabled");
              }else{
           $("#day").attr("disabled", "true");
           }
           });
```

if the value you've selected is "yes" or "maybe" ,the "#day" selectbox will be enabled, else it will be disabled.

Comment: yea, I have misspeled something in @mohkhan example, and that is solution I like the most... thank you

Comment: `attr` isnt used anymore. try changing it to `prop`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this :

```
$("#decide").change(function () {
    $("#day").prop("disabled", !(["yes", "maybe"].indexOf(this.value) !== -1));
});
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/3hwzK/2/

Answer (score 1):

i Added this JS code:

```
$("#decide").change(function () {
  $('#day').prop('disabled', false);  });
```

Working Great in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ahmedadil1000/3hwzK/1/)

Comment: thanks, but that is not solution... because second #day list must be enabled only on select of 'yes:' or 'maybe:' from first list.... on selection of other options, #day would not get enabled

Answer (score 1):

This should work...

```
$(document).on('change', "#decide", function(){
if(this.value == "yes" || this.value == "maybe"){
    $("#day").removeAttr("disabled");
}else{
    $("#day").attr("disabled", "true");
}
});
```

Comment: that is something already... but my real need is to get enabled to yes and maybe option... something like that http://jsfiddle.net/SDzUS/

but not else part seems not to work, why?

Answer (score 1):

you can also use this approach.. http://jsfiddle.net/3hwzK/3/

```
$("#decide").change(function () {
    var valid_answers = ['yes', 'maybe'];
    var is_disabled = ($.inArray($(this).val(), valid_answers) > -1) ? false : true;
    $('#day').prop('disabled', is_disabled); 
});
```